# How can I retrieve by using OpenCV in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I found retrieve function in OpenCV for web camera.
https://github.com/BelBES/HandDetector/blob/master/main.cpp

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(CV_CAP_OPENNI);
cap.retrieve(mat, CV_16UC1);
```

Can I retrieve it the same way in iOS?
I tried like following, but it shows just black.

```
mat.convertTo(depthMap, CV_8UC1, 1.0/255);
```

Any idea?
Or, How can I convert this main.cpp for iOS?

Comment: I'm confused as to how the code examples are related. The other seems to be using a `cv::VideoCapture` to capture data to a `cv::Mat`, while the other is apparently just converting a `cv::Mat` to another type.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS framework `opencv2.framework`, there is a type `CvCapture`, which is the cv::VideoCapture in C++:

[image]

Try it.